# HttpURLConnection returns 503 error when accessed through proxy

Tags: java, http-status-code-503, brightcove

I am working on creating a Video sitemap for a site that has hosted videos on Brightcove video cloud. In order to get all the video information from the site, Brightcove suggests to read the response from their url of following form

```
http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?token="+accountToken+"&page_size=1&command=find_all_videos&output=JSON&get_item_count=true
```

the output of the url is in JSON, where `accountToken` is just an identifier of the account.

When I hit the above url with Token in the browser, it gives me the correct response.

I wrote below program snippet to read from that url

```
URL jsonURL = new URL("http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?token="+accountToken+"&page_size=1&command=find_all_videos&output=JSON&get_item_count=true");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) jsonURL.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String lineRead = "";
        while (reader.ready()) {
            lineRead = lineRead + reader.readLine();
        }
```

As my browser uses proxy, I added below code to include proxy settings

```
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxyurl.com");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

Without using proxy settings, it returns `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` and with proxy it gives me `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503`

So my question is , why is it giving me a 503(Service Unavailable) error ? From the browser its working fine.

**Update 1:**
It seems like an issue with the Network. I pinged the domain and it said "Request Timed out". Working via HTTP though. Looks like an issue with the Firewall.

Comment: @jtahlborn:Reverse proxy. With what context are you asking this ?

Comment: Can you provide with temporary test accountToken?

Comment: is it a socks proxy perhaps?  some other sort of proxy?

Comment: @JamshidAsatillayev: Just remove the token parameter and try. It will return a JSON with an Error message. but that's not working too.

Comment: @jtahlborn: I really don't know. what if it is a socks proxy?

Comment: You probably getting some response body with your 503 response indicating the reason. At minimum, this will contain an indication whether 503 is returned by the proxy or by an API endpoint. Could you try reading the whole HTTP response and posting it here?

Comment: Additionally, I would try using a tool like Wireshark to see the HTTP messages coming in and out -- maybe they not even reaching the proxy, or not being authenticated by it, etc

Comment: I have tried your code (I am *also* behind the proxy) and it worked fine, taking into account these two lines in Jamshid's answer. Check once more if you entered correct address and port and if your proxy has been configured properly, has no security restrictions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, it may due to your internet connection, I have tried your code I didn't get any `503(Service Unavailable)`. Check out with different connection connection(without proxy) and it should work. Or you can try it with slightly different approach:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("host", "port));
conn = new URL(jsonURL).openConnection(proxy);
```

If you have SOCKS type proxy, change `Proxy`'s constructor parameter to `Proxy.Type.SOCKS`.

Comment: I already tried that approach for proxy....didn't try with type Proxy.Type.SOCKS though....let me try it and i ll let you know.....

Comment: Not working. I got `java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server`. No point in trying it in a different connection without proxy.I have to make it work in the client environment which requires proxy..:(

Comment: As you said it looks like a network issue. I have added an update to my question. Your answer surely does deserve this bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction to Jamas code

```
String host="myproxy.com";
int port=8080;
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```